# How to set WLAN card to streaming mode?

Tags: networking, streaming, wifi

I have a requirement where the background network scan should be disabled when there is data transfer happening between devices as it causes break in data. When I went through internet, I found the fix to this problem by turning on streaming mode for the WLAN card on the windows tablet/computer. It says the below variable should be set:

```
OID_802_11_MEDIA_STREAM_MODE
```

But I am not sure, how should I do this ? I am not a networking guy.

I have a 3rd party software(found at: http://www.martin-majowski.de/) that does that. But I dont want to rely on that software. Instead, I want to set it myself or automate it in my WPF application(if possible).

Any leads/answers to this is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After exploring I found the answer to my question. We can set the WlanIntfOpcode.MediaStreamingMode Opcode to true after connecting asynchronously.

Example code:

```
iface.ConnectSynchronously(Wlan.WlanConnectionMode.Profile, Wlan.Dot11BssType.Infrastructure, name, 5000);
iface.MediaStreaming = true;
```

where:

```
public bool MediaStreaming
{
    get
    {
        return GetInterfaceInt(Wlan.WlanIntfOpcode.MediaStreamingMode) != 0;
    }
    set
    {
        SetInterfaceInt(Wlan.WlanIntfOpcode.MediaStreamingMode, value ? 1 : 0);
    }
}
```

Hope its helpful to someone.